# How can I set the port of bitcoind to run Armory through Tor?

Tags: armory, tor

I'm trying to set up Armory with Tor by directing all Armory communications to port 9150 which is the one that I have been told my Tor browser uses.

Before I start Armory or the Tor Browser, I activate bitcoind with the terminal command 'bitcoind -proxy=127.0.0.1:9150'. But when I then start Armory, it tells me that I must shut down this instance of the program and allow Armory to start it instead. OK, but there seems to be no way to inject the command line switches into the version Armory starts.

If I disable the the Armory checkbox 'Let Armory run bitcoind in the background' then it does not give me that objection message but instead never goes online even if I have started bitcoind manually.

There is another thread on this subject but, since I am new here, I don't know if I can just attach a new question to an old thread or must post a new one.  So, I decided to post a new one, sorry if that is not the correct procedure.

And, to address the issue of a Wiki brought up in the older thread, the problem seems to keep changing because the functions of Armory and Tor keep changing. For instance, I can't run Vidalia on my system because I run Ubuntu 12.04 and Vidalia is not available for that version. I must run the Tor browser instead to get activation of the Tor network. So perhaps a Wiki would be good.

Comment: Please provide a link to the related question for reference.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find the older post. I tried to answer with a comment to your comment, but this blog wouldn't let me because I hadn't made enough posts yet.

Answer (score 1):

Having never tried this myself, I can't answer it with my own personal experience.  But there is a thread with input from several people on a question pretty similar to this in Bitcointalk: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=155717.0  That thread may answer your question, and if not, feel free to ask followup questions there.  (There used to be a requirement to be in the newbie forum for a while, but this requirement has since been removed, so all you need to do is create an account on bitcointalk to post questions.)